# Is there a way to uniquely identify a pc even when software is running on a virtual machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, software-distribution

Is there a way to check the actual PC that is running the software even through a VM, like, use a backdoor to talk to the actual computer whilst the software is running on the VM?

My employers are afraid that their users could use their software inside a vitual machina and share the software through many people that way, so I sugested them to make the software not run on VM, but they denied that option, sinse there are some clients who really only run their stuff on VMs.

I'm hoping there is a way to Identify uniquely a PC even if the software is running through a VM, even though that seems like an impossible task.

Comment: most VMs are not even hosted on desktop PCs, but on specialised equipment. And the whole point of virtualisation is to provide a "just-like-real" experience so that software running on the VM doesn't notice it's not on bare metal any more. Besides, like you say, even if you can detect that the software is running on a virtualised environment, that might be a perfectly legitimate usage for that organisation.

Comment: To be honest, you didn't totally make this clear, but it sounds like they are worried about people hosting instances of their software in VMs and then sharing it between users in order to circumvent licensing restrictions? If so, that's something which is best solved by water-tight licensing, a strong relationship with the clients, and some active checking and enforcement measures, if possible. In other words, it's a legal and process issue, not a technical one.

Comment: I suggest you read on the subject of VM. You will learn that you can very easily create perfect clones of VM and you won't see a single difference. You best solution remain adding security on your application such as a login. You can prevent multi login of the same account but that still doesn't prevent a different person from using the account while the other user is not using it. You can make it difficult but cannot fully protect against this.

Comment: @itsme86 I guess OP was hoping for a snippet of C# like `bool result = IsMachineVirtual();` .. :-). But to be honest, by the looks of it the issue at hand is barely about programming of any sort, if it all. Or at least, it's not one that is best solved by code.

Comment: Thank you all, I was under the impression that it would not be possible to do so, but they asked me do it nonetheless, I'll just tell them it's not feasable. I just needed confirmation.

Comment: @ADyson, I wasn't looking for code ahaha, but confirmation if it was at least feasable with code, and yes, some pointers about it if possible.